# Spark-Atlas-Connector NullPointerExceptions during startup

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-atlas

I'm trying to start my job which I've done for testing integration spark with atlas.

This is simple job which reads from one topic and write to another.

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("atlas-test")
      .setMaster("local[2]")
      .set("spark.extraListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker")
      .set("spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasEventTracker")
      .set("spark.sql.streaming.streamingQueryListeners", "com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.SparkAtlasStreamingQueryEventTracker")


    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    val df = spark.read.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BROKER_SERVERS)
      .option("subscribe", "foobar2")
      .option("startingOffset", "earliest")
      .option("kafka.atlas.cluster.name", clusterName)
      .load()

    println("---------------------------------------------")

    df.printSchema()
    val dfs = df.selectExpr("CAST(key as STRING)","CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]

    dfs.show()
    println("---------------------------------------------")

    df.write
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", BROKER_SERVERS)
      .option("topic", "foobar-out")
      .option("kafka.atlas.cluster.name", clusterName)
      .save()
```

Everything seems understandable. So I try to run the job in my IDE (Intellij) and almost everytime I got this exception

```
19/08/12 17:00:08 WARN SparkExecutionPlanProcessor: Caught exception during parsing event
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$14.apply(SQLConf.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$14.apply(SQLConf.scala:133)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.get(SQLConf.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.simpleString(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.verboseString(QueryPlan.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.treeString(TreeNode.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryExecution.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryExecution.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:197)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.CommandsHarvester$.com$hortonworks$spark$atlas$sql$CommandsHarvester$$getPlanInfo(CommandsHarvester.scala:214)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.CommandsHarvester$.com$hortonworks$spark$atlas$sql$CommandsHarvester$$makeProcessEntities(CommandsHarvester.scala:222)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.CommandsHarvester$SaveIntoDataSourceHarvester$.harvest(CommandsHarvester.scala:183)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.SparkExecutionPlanProcessor$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.scala:108)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.SparkExecutionPlanProcessor$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.process(SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.scala:89)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.sql.SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.process(SparkExecutionPlanProcessor.scala:63)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AbstractEventProcessor$$anonfun$eventProcess$1.apply(AbstractEventProcessor.scala:72)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AbstractEventProcessor$$anonfun$eventProcess$1.apply(AbstractEventProcessor.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AbstractEventProcessor.eventProcess(AbstractEventProcessor.scala:71)
    at com.hortonworks.spark.atlas.AbstractEventProcessor$$anon$1.run(AbstractEventProcessor.scala:38)
```

I'm using spark 2.4.0 with scala 2.11

And I have some misunderstanding about result. Honestly can't understand after this job in my atlas (local machine) will appear something? Because sometimes jobs run successful but nothing appears in Atlas.

Comment: Have you verified that the column names and types are correct?  I just ran into this issue (same stack trace) and had the wrong column name/type, which when corrected seemed to have fixed my issue.

Comment: do you find any solution ?

Comment: Is there any solutions?

Comment: i guess this happen when spark context is already shut down with some unrelated issue?